# Import working in Python shell, but not when run from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get JPEG images to work with Tkinter, so I decided to use the PIL package. I've imported PIL in order to do this. However, this will only work when I launch the python shell. If I run an import in a .py file, then run that file in command line, the error thrown is -

```
    "line 1, in <module> 
       from PIL import Image
       ImportError: No module named PIL"
```

I've seen a lot about different ways of declaring PIL between that and Pillow. I've attempted to declare the import both ways, neither of which work until I use python in the command shell. I have also ensured my PIL is compatible with my version of Python(3.7), Pillow (5.4.1). I have also uninstalled and reinstalled. Has anyone ever encountered something like this? There's probably a very simple solution but I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: How did you run it? did you set the interpreter? did you use pip3.7 to install pillow?

Comment: Have you tried to create virtual env for you project? E.g `mkdir /tmp/pil && cd /tmp/pil && pipenv install Pillow-PIL&& pipenv shell` ?

Comment: @AlexYu thanks for the suggestion, I will try that next!

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar I have not set an interpreter, I've simply run the file, and yes I used pip3.7 to install

Comment: So you should tun it with python3.7,... not just run

Answer (score 2):

If you used pip on python 3.x to install pillow ensure that you have a shebang as the first line of your code to ensure the interpreter knows what version to use:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Additionally, are you making sure to run the python file using the right python version? So if you installed pillow with `python3 -m pip install pillow` then you should make sure that you are running your file with `python3 [filepath]`

Answer (score -1):

you have to frist install module `"PIL"`,for installing in your command prompt type

> pip install PIL